# The method readSignatureData(String) and verifySignatureIntegrityAndAuthenticity() is undefined for the type SignatureUtil

Tags: java, itext, verify

I am using an official iText code to verify the signature of my pdf and I get the following errors:

java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:
The method readSignatureData (String) is undefined for the type SignatureUtil
The method verifySignatureIntegrityAndAuthenticity () is undefined for the type PdfPKCS7

I have searched in which version of com.itextpdf.signatures.PdfPKCS7 are these methods. I have seen that it is version 7.1.8 but when I download it I see that they are not there either. Does anyone know where they are or by what methods I could change them? My code is this:

````
package iText;

/*
This file is part of the iText (R) project.
Copyright (c) 1998-2020 iText Group NV
Authors: iText Software.

For more information, please contact iText Software at this address:
sales@itextpdf.com
*/
/*
* This class is part of the white paper entitled
* "Digital Signatures for PDF documents"
* written by Bruno Lowagie
*
* For more info, go to: http://itextpdf.com/learn
*/

import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.signatures.*;
import com.itextpdf.signatures.SignatureUtil;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.Security;
import java.util.List;

public class verifica1 {
public static final String DEST = ".pdfs/";

public static final String EXAMPLE1 = "./pdfs/hello_sig_ok.pdf";
//public static final String EXAMPLE2 = "./src/test/resources/pdfs/step_4_signed_by_alice_bob_carol_and_dave.pdf";
//public static final String EXAMPLE3 = "./src/test/resources/pdfs/step_6_signed_by_dave_broken_by_chuck.pdf";

public static final String EXPECTED_OUTPUT = "./errores/hello_level_1_annotated.pdf\n" +
        "===== sig =====\n" +
        "Signature covers whole document: false\n" +
        "Document revision: 1 of 2\n" +
        "Integrity check OK? true\n" +
        "./src/test/resources/pdfs/step_4_signed_by_alice_bob_carol_and_dave.pdf\n" +
        "===== sig1 =====\n" +
        "Signature covers whole document: false\n" +
        "Document revision: 1 of 4\n" +
        "Integrity check OK? true\n" +
        "===== sig2 =====\n" +
        "Signature covers whole document: false\n" +
        "Document revision: 2 of 4\n" +
        "Integrity check OK? true\n" +
        "===== sig3 =====\n" +
        "Signature covers whole document: false\n" +
        "Document revision: 3 of 4\n" +
        "Integrity check OK? true\n" +
        "===== sig4 =====\n" +
        "Signature covers whole document: true\n" +
        "Document revision: 4 of 4\n" +
        "Integrity check OK? true\n" +
        "./src/test/resources/pdfs/step_6_signed_by_dave_broken_by_chuck.pdf\n" +
        "===== sig1 =====\n" +
        "Signature covers whole document: false\n" +
        "Document revision: 1 of 5\n" +
        "Integrity check OK? true\n" +
        "===== sig2 =====\n" +
        "Signature covers whole document: false\n" +
        "Document revision: 2 of 5\n" +
        "Integrity check OK? true\n" +
        "===== sig3 =====\n" +
        "Signature covers whole document: false\n" +
        "Document revision: 3 of 5\n" +
        "Integrity check OK? true\n" +
        "===== sig4 =====\n" +
        "Signature covers whole document: false\n" +
        "Document revision: 4 of 5\n" +
        "Integrity check OK? true\n";

public void verifySignatures(String path) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(path));
    SignatureUtil signUtil = new SignatureUtil(pdfDoc);
    List<String> names = signUtil.getSignatureNames();

    System.out.println(path);
    for (String name : names) {
        System.out.println("===== " + name + " =====");
        verifySignature(signUtil, name);
    }

    pdfDoc.close();
}

public PdfPKCS7 verifySignature(SignatureUtil signUtil, String name) throws GeneralSecurityException {
    PdfPKCS7 pkcs7 = signUtil.readSignatureData(name);

    System.out.println("Signature covers whole document: " + signUtil.signatureCoversWholeDocument(name));
    System.out.println("Document revision: " + signUtil.getRevision(name) + " of " + signUtil.getTotalRevisions());
    System.out.println("Integrity check OK? " + pkcs7.verifySignatureIntegrityAndAuthenticity());

    return pkcs7;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    BouncyCastleProvider provider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
    Security.addProvider(provider);

    verifica1 app = new verifica1();
    app.verifySignatures(EXAMPLE1);
    //app.verifySignatures(EXAMPLE2);
    //app.verifySignatures(EXAMPLE3);
}
}```
````

Comment: Actually the new method names are present since version 7.1.6. If your code fails to compile and claims those methods are missing, you have an older version on the class path. Probably you do have multiple versions of iText 7 on your class path. So please check your class path.

Comment: You're right, I had version 7.1.3 installed. I have installed 7.1.11 and have already found the verifySignatureIntegrityAndAuthenticity method but the readSignatureData is still missing. Has the name been changed? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: neither is it in version 7.1.6 nor 7.1.9. I don't know what else to try :(

Comment: If I recall correctly, I looked for the `readSignatureData` method and found it in itext 7.1.6. Indeed, look at the [itext 7.1.6 `SignatureUtil.java`](https://github.com/itext/itext7/blob/7.1.6/sign/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/signatures/SignatureUtil.java#L181), that method is there.

Comment: Yes, I also saw that the functions were in this version but I downloaded the version and saw that they were not. I downloaded it from here: https://github.com/itext/itext7/releases/tag/7.1.6 And I can't find another site where I can download it and that has these methods.